# Localhost shows Index of / child directories are 404

Tags: php, apache2, http-status-code-404, lamp

I have a LAMP server on ubuntu 12.04. I haven't touched my own local server in forever but navigated to it recently in firefox and instead of getting the "It Works..." message it says "Index of /" and shows that the directory is empty. 
However, the directory is not empty and it has my index.html file with the "it works.." message in it along with an index.php for testing purposes, and a few other child directories.
Navigating to these directly (localhost/index.html) gives me a 404 same with all the child directories and files within.
I haven't found anyone else who has had this issue. I've tried reinstalling via the purge method all of my lamp stack and that hasn't done anything.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it after doing some more reading on the apache website and noticing some strangeness when trying to connect through different ports. 
in my 000-default.conf file the document root was set to /var/www/html rather than /var/www
!

Comment: Worked... it will be good if you specify location of 000-default.conf to /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf in your answer. :)

Comment: I had the same experience (although it was after an update to 14.04) but don't forget to restart apache2 otherwise it still won't work